# react-native-dotenv error: "Module '"@env"' has no exported member"

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, mobile-development, dotenv

I'm trying to use `react-native-dotenv` package with react-native/expo.

Yesterday I built this and saw no errors with everything working fine. Today I log into my pc, and when I opened my IDE I see the red squiggly lines, but the application runs fine.

I've followed several guides in setting up the types and json config. I can't see why it's giving me the error `Module '"@env"' has no exported member 'TEST_ONE'`. Below are the changes I made to the project to get it working yesterday...

### File/Folder Structure

[image]

### App.tsx

```
...
import { TEST_ONE, TEST_ONE_DEV } from '@env';
...
```

### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  ...
  return {
    ...
    plugins: [
      ...
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv',
        {
          envName: 'APP_ENV',
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: '.env',
          blocklist: null,
          allowlist: null,
          blacklist: null, // DEPRECATED
          whitelist: null, // DEPRECATED
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
          verbose: false
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./app/types"],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

### .env

```
RANDOM_ENV=HelloWorld
```

### .env.development

```
RANDOM_ENV_DEV=HelloWorldDev
```

### ./app/types/Env.ts

```
declare module '@env' {
  export const RANDOM_ENV: string;
  export const RANDOM_ENV_DEV: string;
}
```

#### The application runs fine

[image]

#### The issue is shown below

[image]

Error: `Module '"@env"' has no exported member 'TEST_ONE'.ts(2305)`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just realized I missed the naming...

App.tsx change

```
import { TEST_ONE, TEST_ONE_DEV } from '@env';
```

to

```
import { RANDOM_ENV, RANDOM_ENV_DEV } from '@env';
```

I'll leave this question up here for reference in case anyone needs to see how to set it up with expo.